# Homeomorphism, subspace topology, and basis of topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider the real numbers with the standard topological basis, $\mathcal{B}$, of open intervals: 
$\mathbb{R}$  with $\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b)  |  a,b∈\mathbb{R}, a< b\}$
Also, consider the subset $(0,1)⊂\mathbb{R}$ with the subspace topology.
Define a homeomorphism, $f:\mathbb{R}→(0,1)$, and prove that $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are topologically equivalent.

Comment: Did you attempt any part of this exercise?  It's hard to guess where you might have gotten stuck because the bare statement of an exercise reveals little or nothing about your level of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(y)$

is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$.

Now you only need to find its continuous inverse.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a hint: Use the function "tan x"

;)

Comment: Here is more: [Sigmoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples)